# How to set restriction on checkout shipping step navigate to next button in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, javascript, frontend

I save quote data in one of my custom table in that table grid manage by admin in that I manage on status if this status was enable for that cart and then next button work other wise next button was disable

[image]

I need to set navigate to next button restriction based on that custom table status enable disabled for that cart

Custom Table is

[image]

> Button code File Path :-
> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

```
<div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
                    <div class="primary">
                        <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit"
                         class="button action continue primary"  disabled>
                            <span translate="'Nexts'" />
                        </button>
                    </div>&nbsp &nbsp
                    <div class="primary">
                        <button type="submit" class="button action continue primary" >
                            <span translate="'New Button'" />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you please upload your button code with file path which you used?

Comment: i update my question please review thank you

Answer (score 0):

For this, the process will be like, first create the configprovider, and then you will get the data on JS inside the `window.checkoutConfig...` after that you can write a KO script to disable the field if you have already overwritten the HTML file for the button

```
<button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary"
        data-bind="enable: window.checkoutconfig.mycustomvariabletoconfirm">
    <span translate="'Nexts'" />
</button>
```

> code to create config provider in the etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Modulename\Model\CustomConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

> Namespace/Modulename/Model/CustomConfigProvider.php

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Gateway\Http\Client\ClientMock;

class CustomConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface {
    public function getConfig() {
        $config = ['mycustomvariabletoconfirm' => false];
        return $config;
    }       
}
```